# avilable fields in list view

Tags: list-view

In the application i work, we allow users to create their own list view. But they complain about un-wanted fields listed in available field list. For those fields they have access but they are actually used only for calculation purpose not meant to be displayed.

Any suggestion to remove the unwanted fields from available fields in the list view?

Comment: Do they actually need visibility to the fields? If they are just for calculation and are populated via workflow rules or code then they may not need access to them at all......Otherwise, no way that I am aware of to remove them from the list. And in the grand scheme, if that is all your users are complaining about I would consider it a great thing and revert to the "User Training" solution :)

Comment: Hi Eric,Yes they need access to those fields, because we display some formula fields in page layout, its calculation are based on these fields which do not make any sense to the end users. So we thought of hiding it from them, but now it appears to me that, we will not be able to do it.

Comment: Then you could hide the fields that "Do not make sense" to them potentially

Comment: My understanding, In-order to formula work properly. we have to give access to all the fields referred in the formula. If that is true, how i will be able to hide the fields from them. I  removed it from the page layout, but user are complaining about available fields in the list view.

Comment: As long as they have access to the final field then they will see the value. They do not need access to the parts that make up the formula field. (unless they need to edit them or see them for another reason)

Comment: Is it. I didn't know that, will try and update here.